# Storing Variable in When Tombstone Occurs

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can i store the variables in savestate() method of `TombstoneHelper` class to avoid Tombstone in windows phone 8.

Comment: Give me the reason for minus.

Comment: Probably because you don't show what you have tried so far and you don't give a clue about what kind of class `TombstoneHelper` is. I had to google to find out it is a `CodePlex` project. How to write perfect questions: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I don't know that things butTombstone is Common Problem in Windows Phone.And every Windows Developer Knows "What is "TombstoneHelper" because it is best solutiobn for Tombstone.Have na karto minus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to use PhoneApplicationService.State Property - it works like Dictionary(string, object). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
To save on Deactivated event:

```
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    int myObject = 5;
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add("myName", myObject);
}
```

To restore on Activated event:

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var returnedOnject = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myName"];
}
```

Comment: Well, The Code is right but it gives null value in the variable in after Tombsotne

Comment: I've corrected the code - now it should return 5 on ActivationEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Man +1 For your comment Romasz .It is now working but there is an error when app went to the tombstone stage because PhoneApplicationService State is null when your app comes from the Tombstone Stage.So i stored that phoneState in the isolated storage in application_Deactivated and retrieve from isolated Storage in application_activated.
I made simple LoginData Class where i can store my data that i have to preserving.

```
[DataContract]
    public class LoginData
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool chainmanager { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string logoimage { get; set; }

        public LoginData(string username, string password, int establishmentId, bool ischainmager,string logoimage)
        {
            this.Username = username;
            this.Password = password;
            this.EstablishmentId = establishmentId;
            this.chainmanager = ischainmager;
            this.logoimage = logoimage;

        }
    }
```

Then make method to save the Class object in app.xml

```
 public void save(LoginData ld)
        {
            PhoneApplicationService phonestate = PhoneApplicationService.Current;

                phonestate.State["_lOGINcREDENTIALs_"]= ld;
                var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                settings["Credatials"] = phonestate.State["_lOGINcREDENTIALs_"];

        }
```

And Method to load the Class object

```
public void load()
        {
            PhoneApplicationService phonestate = PhoneApplicationService.Current;
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            object credentials;
            if (settings.TryGetValue("Credatials", out credentials))
            {

                phonestate.State["_lOGINcREDENTIALs_"]= credentials;
            }

        }
```

and call these methods in various event like

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        load();
    }
 private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
  {
        load();
  }
 private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
  {
       save();
  } 
 private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
  {
      save();
  }
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by null in PhoneApplicationService. It should work, and the data should persist between states: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/05/23/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example.html . But I'm glad that you have found your solution.